# Shared link between non-relativistic QM and Special Relativity: Proper time?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

So in the path integral formulation of QM, each path gets weighted by a phase factor of $e^{iS/ \hbar}$, where S indicates the classical action of the path. For a small displacement in space and time (or for a free particle), we have $S = \vec{p} \cdot \Delta \vec{x} - E \Delta t$. Or writing the momentum-energy 4-vector as the $\vec{m} = (\vec{p},E)$ ($\vec{m}$ because the magnitude is the mass $m$), and writing the space-time displacement vector as $\vec{\tau} = (\vec{x},t)$, we have that the action is $S = \vec{m} \cdot \vec{\Delta \tau}$.

Therefore the phase factor in (non-relativistic mind you!) quantum mechanics for a small displacement (or free particle) is $e^{i\vec{m} \cdot \vec{\Delta \tau}/ \hbar}$. Is this not a huge clue to special relativity? That the non-relativistic QM phase factor just seems to beg for an organization into 4-momentum and 4-displacement?

Seems to me that the natural interpretation is that each oscillation of a quantum wave, a system gets to spend $\hbar$ action on whatever it "wants". And that mass is best thought of as a 4-vector quantity saying how much action you spend per 4-displacement. i.e. the "mass" 4-vector is the gradient of action with respect to 4-displacement.

**Question:** Is there any significance to this observation, or resources that have taken this line of thought further?